# Initializing objectify in google app engine

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, objectify, datastore

I need to use objectify version 5 with my app engine spring project. What is the initialization code for using objectify with GAE. I've tried creating a class as mentioned in [https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup](http://github%20objectify%20documentation) , but it does't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special initialization required for Objectify v5. Just make sure you register your entities before you start using Objectify; a servlet context listener is ideal.